# CPE and base station configuration in OPNET modeller

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, wimax

i am trying to simulate a network of 5 laptops communicating to CPE which also communicates to the Base station. the base station connects to the router and finally to the eternet. from the internet a server is connected. i want to send video from the laptop to the server.how do i configure the Base station and CPE?

Comment: I see you tagged this "WiMax". When you say CPE, do you mean a WiMax gateway at a customer's site? Are the 5 laptops connecting to that box via Wi-Fi? When you talk about the "base station" that the CPE connects to, is that a WiMax base transceiver station (BTS, like a cell tower) that the WiMax carrier owns? Is the router and Ethernet also part of the carrier's equipment at the WiMax BTS site?